# build a Linked list from a normal list

Tags: kotlin

Hello i try to build a Linked list from a normal list in kotlin.
i try to do this in a init block which i already write.
i do not know how to initialize the passed people into a linked list

```
data class Human(val name: String, val nameTwo: String, val age: Double, val size: Int)

class LinkedListLibrary(list: List<Human>) {

    data class HumanNode(val human: Human, var next: HumanNode?)

    private var first: HumanNode? = null

    fun addFirst(human: Human) {
        first = HumanNode(human, first)
    }

    init {

    }
```

Comment: Just put `list.forEach { human -> addFirst(human) }` inside your `init` block.

Comment: ok thanks, but can you explain me that ?

Comment: The `forEach` method of a list will receive a function (the `{ ... }` part). This function must contain one argument, that in this case we're calling `human` (the `human ->` part). So the `forEach` method will execute this function for every object inside the list `list`, so the code will execute `addFirst(human)` for every human in the list passed in the constructor (i.e. it'll add every human in the list to the linked list).

Comment: Won't that reverse the order of the original list? I think there should be an `addLast` function added, and that should be used instead.

Comment: Is this for educational purpose? Because you could use the existing LinkedList implementation otherwise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're targeting the JVM or Android platform, you can use the built-in `LinkedList` implementation:

```kotlin
import java.util.LinkedList

val original = listOf(1, 2, 3)
val linked = LinkedList(original)
```

If you're targeting another platform, or you just want to implement it yourself, you have several options.

The simplest is to just iterate the reversed source list, and insert elements using your existing `addFirst` method:

```kotlin
init {
    list.asReversed().forEach { addFirst(it) }
}
```

Another option is to implement an `add` (or `addLast`) method and use it for intialization by iterating the original list normally:

```
init {
    list.forEach { addLast(it) }
}
```